# Nullpointer Exception on Server Response

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I created an application that helps users login to an online server using APIs. I use retrofit to help me make network calls to the server. Strangely some devices like tablets and apps like blue stacks gets null pointer exception when the response from the server is null. Kindly help me fix the null pointer exception.
**NB: There are so many questions on Null pointer Exception but none is tailored to fit my question.**

This is my codes below

```
public void loginUser(String userName, String userPassword, Boolean userRememberMe) {

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getClient(authUser.getToken());
    APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);


    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "...", false, false);
    loading.show();

    mAPIService.loginUser(userName, userPassword, userRememberMe).enqueue(new Callback<LendingResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<LendingResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if(response.isSuccess()) {

                String userId = response.body().getData().getId();
                String userName = response.body().getData().getUsername();
                String name = response.body().getData().getName();
                String phoneNumber = response.body().getData().getPhoneNumber();
                String email = response.body().getData().getEmail();
                String token =response.body().getData().getToken();
                String gender = response.body().getData().getGender();


                loading.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loading.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

This is my error logs from the play store below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 

at com.jonathan.lendingsquare.auth.LoginActivity$3.onResponse (Unknown Source)

at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run (Unknown Source)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5001)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:793)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:609)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

Comment: Check your api response with same request on web rest client like Postman. Handle the exception with try-catch on response as its always exception prone code  block .

Comment: @AMD it works with postman message body is never null..it is just strange i get null messages when using blue stacks..would surround that block of code with try catch

Comment: Check the Model class you assign to retrofit . There must be some parsing issue.

Answer (score 3):

Remove progress dialog than test it.

Other wise check following null or not

boolean mSuccess = false;

```
                if (response.isSuccessful())

                    if (response.body() != null)

                        if(response.body().getStatus().getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.getInstance().True))

                            mSuccess = true;

                if (mSuccess) {

                   //your code`enter code here`
                }
```

Comment: what is this line checking for if(response.body().getStatus().getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.getInstance().True))

Comment: This line checking for you API response  success true or false or otherwise 1 or 0 whatever we get result

Answer (score 0):

Just check the value `null` or not:

```
if (!(signUp_jsonObject.isNull(response.body().getData().getId())))
{ 
    String userId = response.body().getData().getId();
}
```

Comment: `if (!signUp_jsonObject.isNull(response.body().getData().getId()))` is enough (removed parentheses)

Comment: @DanielAlder It's totally depend on your response.In my Code i generally use to check 2 things Whether key is exists and value associated to that key is null or not.

                           if(jsonObject.has("exists"))
                            {
                                if (!(jsonObject.isNull("exists")))
                                {
                                   -----
                                }
                            }

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I was only saying that `if (!(bool))` and `if (!bool)` are the same

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
       //Code here

}
```